# Import all project files at once?

Tags: java, eclipse

### Background:

My Java book comes with exercise files (about 200 files organized by chapter).

### Goal:

I'm trying to import the entire "exercise files" directory or entire "chapter" directories with one action.

Switch through the exercise files more quickly than possible with the 'File->Open' dialogues?

### Question:

Is this possible in Eclipse?  If so, how?  If not, is there something similar or an action like this from a different IDE?

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313858/importing-multiple-projects-into-eclipse?

Comment: Yes.  But the phrasing here is more obvious.  Thank you, @AulisRonkainen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into workspace` -option to import multiple projects to your workspace.

Like @Andrew Eisenberg answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313909/1997776:

> If all of your old projects exist in a single directory or in a single parent directory, you can do **File -> Import... -> Existing Projects into workspace**. Choose a root directory that is a parent all of the projects you want to import. You will then be able to import all of the projects at once.